# Javascript POST input file to API and get response

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am testing out [CamCard API](https://dev.camcard.com/) and I wonder how should I post the image taken by my camera to the API and get the response and display it in my page?

That's the sample code they provide and I would like to know how can I achieve to take picture from webcam and POST it to API and get response and display.

Any guidance would be appreciated :)
[image: sample]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Jpeg_Camera](https://github.com/amw/jpeg_camera) library to take a picture from the webcam.

And you can post the output using ajax post to the required destination and can use the ajax response as per your need.

> Load Jpeg_camera

```
<script src="/jpeg_camera/jpeg_camera_with_dependencies.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

```js
var camera = new JpegCamera("#camera");

var snapshot = camera.capture();

snapshot.show(); // Display the snapshot

snapshot.upload({api_url: "<your CamCard url>"})
.done(function(response) {
  response_container.innerHTML = response; // display your response
  this.discard(); // discard snapshot and show video stream again
}).fail(function(status_code, error_message, response) {
  alert("Upload failed with status " + status_code);
});
```

Comment: could you provide me some sample code of the ajax implementation? I tried so many times but just couldn't make it work

Comment: Show what code you have tried so far. 
Based on that, we can provide.

Comment: `
        $.ajax({
         url: 'the API link that they provide', // is this correct?
         type: 'POST',
         data: {
          'action': 'follow',
          'file': $('#file').val(),   //what should i put here??
         },
         success: function(data, status) {
          alert(data);
         },
         error: function(xhr, desc, err) {
         }
       }); `

Comment: Okay. I added code for usage of jpeg_camera in my answer.